# cypress - Identify an element with mouse event for the element with css property "display: none"

Tags: cypress

I am trying to click an element (ellipsis) that will appear after the *mouse-enter* event on a particular list element but the test fails with the following error.

```
Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:
<button id="optionsButton">...</button>

This element <button#optionsButton> is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none
Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking
```

My code:

```
cy.get("voy-vessel-gsis-list-entry")
      .find('.container')
      .eq(0)
      .should('be.visible')
      .trigger("mouseenter")
      .find('#optionsButton')
      .click()
```

I also checked similar questions in sof and tried `invoke('show')` but none worked (so far).

Here is the DOM:

[image]

when mouse hover/enter event on `.container`:

[image]

when no mouse event:

[image]

Comment: Hey Dhamo, did you try `.click({force:true})`?

Comment: Yes, Sarah, I tried it even before a recommendation from the error but it didn't work

Comment: I figured so. Sometimes you can `.focus()` the container to obtain hover (depends on where the events are attached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) plugin. This will work with all chromium browsers, which means firefox will not work.

1.Install the plugin with `npm install cypress-real-events`

2.Then add in `cypress/support/index.js`

```
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```

3.Then you can use `realHover('mouse')`.

```
cy.get("voy-vessel-gsis-list-entry")
    .find('.container')
    .eq(0)
    .realHover('mouse')
    .find('#optionsButton')
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()
```

Comment: Thank you @Alapan, the workaround works. Just curious if we have an option in cypress itself without using the external plugin.

Comment: Hi @Dhamo Unfortunately cypress doesn't have something called `cy.hover()`. It achieves the hovering by workarounds. You can look into here more https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover#Workarounds

Comment: It is very unlikely to get it fixed by cypress as [it](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/10) is open since 2015.